# Git Features not Working in VS Code, Windows 10

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a few computers I dev on, been using VS Code for many years, never had a problem. But my new computer's VS Code is missing most Git features, can't even `Git Fetch` from VS Code, BUT git works great in CMD, Powershell, and Git Bash.

My setup is:
Windows 10.0.19041
VS Code 1.52.1
Git for Windows 2.30.0.windows.1

I have an SSH key with a passphrase in:
`C:/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa`

The sidebar Git seems to do local tasks, it will tell me how many files have been modified, and I can commit from there. I'm (sorely) missing the gutter changed/added indicators, and when I try to use `Git Fetch` from the command bar (Ctrl + P) it fails, here's the output:

```
> git fetch
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\wesru\reveal.js\css-training-rh.html
> git cat-file -s 9bf549982195171a7da63ada6e04fa5fa6561242
> git show --textconv :css-training-rh.html
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse gh-pages
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name gh-pages@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right gh-pages...refs/remotes/origin/gh-pages
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\wesru\reveal.js\.git\refs\remotes\origin\gh-pages', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
```

It's a public repo on Github, on my local file system. It makes *no sense* why I can't fetch.

I can press `Ctrl` backtick to get a powershell console and type `git fetch -v` and get:

```
PS C:\Users\wesru\reveal.js> git fetch -v
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\wesru\.ssh\id_rsa': 
From github.com:wesruv/reveal.js
 = [up to date]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
```

I have tried:

- Reinstalled Git and VS Code
- Simplifying `.gitconfig` in my Users folder
- Adding more specificity and adding github.com IdentityFile
- Specifying `git.path` in VS Code to `C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` (and validated that VS Code was using htem in the Git Output
- Reinstalling Git for Windows and using Pageant/Plink for SSH (but I've reinstalled again and gone to OpenSSH)
- Probably other things

Nothing seems to work. :(

Comment: When you use powershell : do you type your passphrase each time ? It may have to do with VS Code fetching with a non interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

To use a passphrase protected key in a non interactive session (e.g : `git fetch` run by VS Code), you would need to set up an ssh-agent, and check that VS Code is started with the correct environment to access that agent.

Comment: Any idea how to check VS Code's environment? I have the same SSH key on other machines and none of these issues :/

Comment: open a terminal from VSCode and run `env | sort` -- not a perfect answer : the shell may have extra variables coming from its config files (e.g : `.bashrc`), but if something is missing (say : no `SSH_AGENT` variable), it is also missing from VS Code

Comment: Another way (suggested on the docs site : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value) : create a task which runs `echo $SOMEVAR` -- you can try `echo $SSH_AGENT; echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, or `env | grep SSH`